# Can Hoeffding's inequality be applied to independent random variables or must they be IID?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, upper-lower-bounds

I want to clarify the assumptions for random variables for which we can apply Hoeffding's inequality. I know that they have to be independent and both upper- and lower-bounded. However, I've seen proofs and lectures that say they have to be independent AND identically distributed (bottom of first page [here](https://people.cs.umass.edu/%7Edomke/courses/sml2010/10theory.pdf), first theorem [here](https://zcc1307.github.io/courses/csc588sp21/notes/0126.pdf)), while others just require independence (theorem 4 on pg. 6 [here](http://cs229.stanford.edu/extra-notes/hoeffding.pdf), first page [here](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Elarry/=stat700/Lecture6.pdf), section 3 on pg. 2 [here](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Ecscott/past_courses/eecs598w14/notes/03_hoeffding.pdf)). Which is correct? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Of course you shouldn't rely on only Wikipedia and look at its sources, but it seems like Hoeffing's inequality is indeed true for just indepednent random variables: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality. This is just a comment since it's only one more point for the "only independence" camp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many variants of it. Consider random variables $X_1$, $X_2$, $\dots$ . Also, assume that for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$,  $|X_i|\leq b$ with probability one and $\mathbb{E}[X_i]=0$. If $X_i$s are independent, then, for every $\delta$ and $n$, with probability at least $1-\delta$ we have
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i \leq b \sqrt{\frac{2 \log(2/\delta)}{n}}.
\end{align}

To obtain a bound like this, even independence is **not** required. For instance, you can take a look at [Azuma's inequality](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs265/Lectures/Lecture16/l16.pdf). Also, the boundedness can be relaxed using the notion of Subgaussian tails ([here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.2392.pdf)).